# Code runs fine when stepped through but bombs when simply run

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA program that I'm working on which seems to work just when I use F8 to step through the program.  I can do this and go from start to finish on the program and it has no problems.  However, If i press F5 and run the program, it bombs causing excel to close and restart (no error message is given) 
:(

I've narrowed it down to something happening in one particular module but lacking any indication as to what it is, I can't seem to find what is wrong.

Any help is very very greatly appreciated

The module that seems to be giving me the issue is:

```
Sub gwLoadWheels(ByRef db As DAO.Database, ByRef pColl As clsParts, ByRef pCrib As clsCrib, ByRef pExcept As clsExceptions)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim iSH As Worksheet
    Dim cWheel As clsCribItem
    Dim rPart As clsPart
    Dim rExcept As clsException
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        For Each rPart In pColl
            sSQL = "SQL String Removed, Verified using SQL Query in MS Access"
            Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
            If Not rs.EOF Then
                rs.MoveLast
                rs.MoveFirst
                For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount
                    If pCrib.ItemExists(rs!wheel_ID) = False Then
                        With pCrib
                            .AddItem (rs!wheel_ID)
                            With .Item(rs!wheel_ID)
                                .AveragePieces = rs!Avg_Pieces
                                .Burn = rs!BurnQty
                                .Cost = rs!AvgUnitCost
                                .HoleDiameter = rs!Hole
                                .OnHand = rs!OnHand
                                .OnOrder = rs!OnOrder
                                .OrderQty = rs!OrderQty
                                .OutsideDiameter = rs!OD
                                .Radius = rs!Radius
                                .Spec = rs!Specification
                                .Treatment = rs!Treat
                                .Width = rs!Width
                                .TotalPieces = rs!Number_Per * rPart.Qty
                            End With
                        End With
                    Else
                        pCrib.Item(rs!wheel_ID).TotalPieces = pCrib.Item(rs!wheel_ID).TotalPieces + (rs!Number_Per * rPart.Qty)
                    End If
                Next i
            Else
                With pExcept
                    .AddException (rPart.PartID)
                    .Exception(rPart.PartID).Qty = .Exception(rPart.PartID).Qty + rPart.Qty
                End With
            End If
            rs.Close
            Set rs = Nothing
        Next rPart
        GoTo SubExit
ErrHandler:
        MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Info"
        i = i
SubExit:
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA is notorious about their corrupt modules. yours is probally corrupt aswell. you just have to create a new project and just paste the code in there.

Comment: I don’t see any error handling here.  What is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message.  Excel simply closes (all open workbooks are closed) and restarts

Comment: I've added some error handling code but it has not changed the results.  Excel simply gives up and crashes.  No error message or anything

Comment: have u tried what I suggested?

Comment: I have tried recreating everything in a new project (took a bit because of my class modules) but still get the same result

Comment: I've found that if I set a break point on the line that calls this routine and a break point on the `End Sub` line of this routine and press F5, the program will run and as expected, break on the line that calls gwLoadWheels.  Once I've stepped into the routine (very first line) I can press F5 and allow the code to run until it reaches the break point on the `End Sub` line and it will run perfectly fine.  It is only when I do NOT break going into the sub that the crash happens

Comment: with regard to the error messages, do you have it set to break on errors in class modules?

Comment: Yes, I have it set to break on errors in class modules

Comment: I've found that if I move the above code into the routine that would have called it, the code seem to run with no issues  :/